# Not able to boot ubuntu after windows drive format

Tags: boot, kernel

I formatted one of the partitions of my Windows 8 drive after which my Ubuntu is not booting. I am using a dual boot system with Ubuntu 12.04 release.

On booting, grub menu is displayed properly. Since it was not booting, i tried booting in recovery mode. I was able to get into recovery mode but fsck was getting stuck. So i went to root shell. I verified that all my data is present but fsck was failing with UUID error. On looking at /etc/fstab and blkid output, the UUID displayed for '/' as well as swap were different. I modified the UUID in fstab to the ids displayed in blkid. Still problem remains the same.

When Ubuntu boots, it just hangs with no error getting displayed, verified this in boot console. Seems like when Windows drive is formatted, partition table got changed.

Please suggest on how to recover from this problem.

Note: I am not able to capture the output of commands as it is booting only in recovery mode. Also when i try to enable network in recovery mode, that also hangs.

Regards,
Manjul

Comment: any error shown or not??????? plz upload screenshot..

Comment: This question seems to have been abandoned. There has not been further information or activity added to it for several months, and the questioner has not logged in since it was posted.  I am flagging this to be closed. If you think this issue is still affecting you, you can flag a moderator to re-open it.